# How to find and replace word inside a file multiple files

Tags: github, replace, find

I have an angular project folder which has lots of ts files. I would like to find all the occurrence of the word "client" and change to "customer" in the whole project i.e. replace action need to be done at the code level inside each files as well as at the file name.